# ParseQueryAdapter "load more..." text

Tags: android, parse-platform, adapter

How to customize "Load more..." inscription in ParseQueryAdapter in Android? It appears when we have more then 25 items in adapter.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ParseQueryAdapter in your custom adapter, you can try this. It worked for me.

Override this method

```
@Override
public View getNextPageView(View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
   //   v = getDefaultView(parent.getContext());
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_home_footer, null);
        /*
         *R.layout.activity_home_footer is your custom layout which contains a TextView named btn_load_more*
         */
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_load_more); //set the button
    textView.setText("Load more... (Customized Load more button)");
    return v;
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is the correct answer, it should be marked as correct by the OP.